# How do you configure ConEmu to run cmd.exe as an Administrator from an Explorer integration?

Tags: command-line, conemu

I am trying to add a [ConEmu Here](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/) - **Explorer context menu integration** entry for the Visual Studio 2012 command prompt.  I want the shortcut to **Run as Administrator**.  I am not sure of the *right* way to do this in ConEmu.

I am using the following Command (which works but obviously not as Admin):

```
cmd.exe /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86
```

What is the correct way to configure ConEmu to run this as Administrator?  If there is not a correct way, how should I adjust the command to make this work?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Add the following [switch](https://conemu.github.io/en/NewConsole.html#syntax) at the end of your command

```
-new_console:a
```

Comment: This should be on the tooltip or should be a predefined item.

Comment: It's impossible to integrate full documentation in the tooltip. https://conemu.github.io/en/NewConsole.html#syntax

Comment: -new_console:a would be enough :)