# How to make conemu windows key hotkeys work for mintty admin child windows?

Tags: hotkeys, conemu, mintty, windows-10-v1511

I am using ConEmu on Windows 10v1511 and when I open a new mintty console with -new_console:a (as explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/470408/how-do-you-configure-conemu-to-run-cmd-exe-as-an-administrator-from-an-explorer)) then certain hotkeys (win+q, win+1-9) stop behaving as normal - it appears to be overridden by Windows functions for those keys, and nothing happens in ConEmu.

For example: win+q is bind to close active console, which works normally - but launched as admin, it opens the "Hi, I'm Cortana" screen on Windows.

admin shell integration i'm using:
`c:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe /bin/sh -lc 'cd "$(cygpath "${%ConEmuWorkDir%}")"; exec bash' -new_console:a`

alternate task i'm using: `c:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe - -new_console:a`

How can I make this work the same as my normal mintty and console windows? Did I do something wrong? I will prefer to fix this in the ConEmu way than disabling those in Windows if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: What has ConEmu got to do with mintty running bash? ConEmu is a cmd replacement not a bash replacement. It is not clear what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: well, ConEmu can have child windows inside it, handles tabbing and splits, etc. I wanted to point it out in-case it's an issue with mintty process in particular

Comment: So you are trying to run ConEmu **inside** of mintty?

Comment: `-new_console:a` is a switch for `ConEmu`. You can't pass it as an argument to `mintty`.

Comment: i'm running mintty 'inside' of conemu

Comment: No you aren't. `c:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe - -new_console:a` runs mintty as a login shell with the argument `-new_console:a`. Running that command gives an error "Failed to run -: No such file or directory"

Comment: @DavidPostill Please don't mislead users with your comments if your are not aware of the [subject](https://conemu.github.io/en/Delusions.html). ConEmu is terminal. bash, as like as cmd, is console application. Both (cmd **and** bash) may be started as shells in ConEmu. And when user run `c:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe - -new_console:a` as a "shell" for new ConEmu tab, `-new_console:a` is processed **internally** by ConEmu and of course it's not passed to `mintty`!

Comment: @xxami **Why** users are still trying to run `mintty` in ConEmu? Read [docs](https://conemu.github.io/en/ChildGui.html). And run `bash` instead of it. (It's like "Run bash in Ubuntu, started in VirtualBox in Windows. What for? Use native console app.)

Comment: @Maximus I am aware of the subject. The OP has posted a completely unclear question. He has not posted exactly what he is trying to do and only given half the information. I was trying to get him to clarify his question.